# What is the BDD feature file format for importing into TestRail?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, bdd, testcase, testrail

I'm unable to import existing BDD feature files from my Automation Framework into TestRail. I'm using the '[Import .feature files into TestRail](https://support.gurock.com/hc/en-us/articles/7827238336916-Behavior-Driven-Development-BDD-#import-feature-files-as-test-cases-0-3)' feature but the file imports without any testcases, neither can I edit the test case to add them manually.

[Using import .feature file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5W4e.png)

[The content inside the testcase did not upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAHQ3.png)

I'm not understanding if my .feature file has to be a specific format for this to work or is this feature not properly working. Some please help.

I tried changing the format of content inside the .feature file but haven't been successful. I suspect there is some format that I have to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem.
In the first release of this feature in TestRail I have found that the import .feature files option creates new test cases but it does not set the BDD template for the test cases it creates.
So what you are seeing is that your import has worked, new test cases have been created but they are all set to use the normal Text template not the BDD template.

I have also noticed that TestRail import of .feature files can't cope with comments at the top of the file.  So I had to strip these out.

[Set the test case template type to be BDD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKf4q.jpg)